# LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE with incremental field

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x

I have multiple unstructured txt files in a directory and I want to insert all of them into mysql; basically, the entire content of each text file should be placed into a row  . In MySQL, I have 2 columns: ID (auto increment), and LastName(nvarchar(45)). I used Python to connect to MySql; used LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE to insert the whole content. But when I run the code I see the following messages in Python console:
[image].
Also, when  I check MySql, I see nothing but a bunch of empty rows with Ids being automatically generated. 
[image]
Here is the code:

```
import MySQLdb
import sys
import os
result = os.listdir("C:\\Users\\msalimi\\Google Drive\\s\\Discharge_Summary")
for x in result:
     db = MySQLdb.connect("localhost", "root", "Pass", "myblog")
     cursor = db.cursor()
     file1 = os.path.join(r'C:\\Discharge_Summary\\'+x)     
     cursor.execute("LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '%s' INTO TABLE clamp_test" %(file1,));         
     db.commit()
db.close()
```

Can someone please tell me what is wrong with the code? What is the right way to achieve my goal?

Comment: It's trying to parse the ID column from your data... Read the error `Incorrect Integer`

Comment: Why can't you just parse the file yourself in Python?

Comment: @cricket_007 thanks, I am new to Phyton and not much familiar with it. Can you please instruct me how to do that?

Comment: I can't see your file, but 1) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26903304/reading-data-from-a-csv-file-in-python 2) https://stackoverflow.com/q/5687718/2308683

Answer (score 0):

I edited my code with:

```
.....cursor.execute("LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '%s' INTO TABLE clamp_test LINES TERMINATED BY '\r' (Lastname) SET id = NULL" %(file1,))
```

and it worked :)