# How to open .csv files in Python

Tags: python, windows, numpy, csv, file

I am trying to open this file called inflammation-01.csv.
The full activity can be found here

https://swcarpentry.github.io/python-novice-inflammation/02-numpy/index.html.

It carries on saying that it cannot find the specifed file.

```
import numpy
fname= ('inflammation-01.csv')
numpy.loadtxt(fname, delimiter=',')
```

Thank you for any help.

Comment: what is the issue your facing here?

Comment: is the file in the same directory you're running the script from?

Comment: make sure `inflammation-01.csv` is in same directory as your py file else you have to specify the full path

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reading data from a CSV file in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26903304/reading-data-from-a-csv-file-in-python)

Comment: Well I am running it in a Jupyter Notebook so how do I put that in the same directory. I specified a path but it still said could not find. Thank you for the link I tried the codes from the link bu they did not work.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to have the CSV file in the same directory as your program running 

Or you may use whole directory to the CSV file

Just some suggestion from me:
You may use module `pandas` to work with csv file

```
import pandas as pd 
data = pd.read_csv("filename.csv") 
data.head()
```

More information:
https://www.shanelynn.ie/python-pandas-read_csv-load-data-from-csv-files/

More detail about pandas:https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/index.html#user-guide

Goodluck with your project :D

Answer (score 0):

Is the file in the same folder, than the script you are running? If not try:

```
fname= (r'C:\<path_to__File>\inflammation-01.csv')
```

replacing `C:\<path_to__File>` with the correct path.

The "r" in front of the filename makes it a raw string, which often helps avoiding problems with backslashes in path names.

Comment: Can you post the error message? Will help to identify the problem. Maybe there are non-numerical column headers? Then this will do the job: 
`import numpy
fname= (r'C:\Temp\inflammation-01.csv')
data = numpy.loadtxt(fname, delimiter=';', skiprows=1)`