# How to add a csv as an input in a function

Tags: python, dataframe

I'm trying to create a function that takes a CSV input but when I try to input a csv like

`function('sample.csv')`

it only views the input as a string.

Comment: You'll have to open the CSV file to access its contents.
Check out the documentation on [csv files](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.reader) in python.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reading data from a CSV file in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26903304/reading-data-from-a-csv-file-in-python)

Answer (score 1):

You're referencing a string in the function. You need to read the CSV file and then use it as an argument. With pandas it can be done as follows:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('sample.csv')
function(df)
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly what you're trying to do, something like this should do the trick:

```
import pandas as pd

def myfunc(csv_path):
    df = pd.read_csv(csv_path)
    return df

myfunc('sample.csv')
```